# How to make sure I use the latest installed kernel?

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I've just installed 16.04 and because of repetitive freezes, I searched and found that I may have to change my kernel version. Before that I think I was running on 4.8.0, at least that was what `uname -r` told me.

So I installed 4.7.0 just in case the other one was too new, but after a couple of checks I'm not sure whether my system really runs on 4.7.0 or it still runs on the older kernel. I followed the instructions at [How To Update / Install Linux Kernel 4.7-RC3 On Ubuntu 16.04](http://sourcedigit.com/19889-how-to-update-install-linux-kernel-4-7-rc3-on-ubuntu-16-04/).

I did run `sudo update-grub`.

This the what I have in my `/boot` directory:

```
$ ls /boot
abi-4.4.0-72-generic                lost+found
abi-4.7.0-040700rc3-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-4.8.0-36-generic                memtest86+.elf
abi-4.8.0-46-generic                memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-4.4.0-72-generic             System.map-4.4.0-72-generic
config-4.7.0-040700rc3-generic      System.map-4.7.0-040700rc3-generic
config-4.8.0-36-generic             System.map-4.8.0-36-generic
config-4.8.0-46-generic             System.map-4.8.0-46-generic
efi                                 vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
grub                                vmlinuz-4.7.0-040700rc3-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic         vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
initrd.img-4.7.0-040700rc3-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic
initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic         vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.8.0-46-generic
```

`uname -r` returns the same thing as before: `4.8.0-46-generic`

And this is my `cat /proc/version`:

```
Linux version 4.8.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy01-15) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:51:03 UTC 2017
```

So my guess is that I did install them but I have to somehow remove the old files. However, I did not want to dive into deleting stuff before asking.

Also, as a side note, do you think it's a good idea at all for me to downgrade my kernel? It's just that I've tried everything and my machine keeps freezing.

Comment: `uname` shows the kernel in use.

Comment: So this means that I did not actually install anything?

Comment: You installed some other kernels like a mainline `4.7.0-040700rc3`. The system boots with the newest kernel by default.

Comment: I want to run on `4.7.0`. So can I just delete everything that contains `4.8.0` from /boot and that's it?

Comment: No, never delete anything from `/boot`. You will break the package system. You can uninstall kernels using `dpkg` or `apt`. And you can always boot any kernel you like using grub menu. And I do not think that fiddling with kernels can be of any help. It is better to address a real issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're going down the entirely wrong path**.

If you're running 16.04.2 you were already running on kernel 4.8. You downgraded to kernel 4.7rc3! (*rc3 means release candidate 3... if you're going to another kernel, at least pick a final release*). It's still booting the 4.8 kernel because you haven't either chosen the 4.7 kernel boot in GRUB, or removed the 4.8 kernel and updated GRUB. Better to purge the 4.7 kernel that you installed.

**Also, you need to do a fsck on your system disk, 'cause it looks like you've got some disk corruption... or a failing hard disk drive... probably the REAL reason why you're freezing**.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Also, you should use the `Disks` application to check the SMART data in your hard disk, looking for failure data. You can also run the SMART tests there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I will purge 4.7 and 4.4. I tried the solution you recommended and I don't think it actually did anything. It just said "Pass1, Pass2..." and didn't throw any errors. Does this mean my disk is not corrupted? Also it's an SSD not an HDD, if that matters in any way.

Comment: @BuckRuck good, that means that your file structure is good, but there still could be trouble. If you look in your /boot directory you'll see a `lost+found`, and that only occurs if there's potential trouble. You need to use the `Disks` app to review the SMART data, and run the SMART tests, and then you need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run a badblock scan on your SSD (**sudo e2fsck -c -k /dev/sda**).

Answer (score 0):

While booting, if you have multiple kernels, grub will show a menu. The first option will be the default kernel to boot, 4.8 in your case. The second option will be something like "Advanced options for Ubuntu". Enter in the menu and you'll see all the installed kernels in your system. If you've successfully installed 4.7.0, there should be an option called "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.7.0 generic". Select that and press Enter. Your system should boot to desktop using 4.7. Don't select the ones ending with (upstart) and (recovery mode), you probably don't need them now.
And for the latest kernel, you can always get that from

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

And then use `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install them.
The latest kernel is 4.10.9 as of today.